# vi, set user settings

Tags: linux, vi

When using vi I almost always need to do

```
:set hlsearch
:set number
```

How can I make my system always load these as presets or something when I use vi.

In one machine I am root, in another not. So please include an answer for both. Thank you!

Comment: (hlsearch is for vim). When you are root, you might be changing things your colleagues don't like. Are you using a terminal emulator / ssh client where you can define key-sequences? Than you might put your favorite lines under a special key-combination.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

just create a `.vimrc` file with the following entries:

```
set hlsearch
set number
```

Put this file in the `$HOME` directory of the user you are using on the particular machine:

`/root/`on the machine where you are `root`.
`/home/USERNAME`on the machine where your user is `USERNAME`

if .vimrc does not exist, create it.

Comment: This is valid for vim, not vi

Comment: On most systems `vi` and `vim` are symlinks to the same binary

Comment: @davir Then install vim first, vim is the most basic tool.

Comment: OP asked about vi, not vim.

Comment: in my directory I have only `.viminfo` . Not `.vimrc`.
I dont know if it will work for vi or vim or both, i will try and tell you

Comment: the .vimrc has all the history etc that is relevant wether I open vi or vim,
but its a little chaotic, if I should add the commands there, where should I exactly?

Comment: @thahgr If you don't have a `.vimrc`already simply create a new one. The `.viminfo` file has some informations that vim itself use to store the current state of the vim session in order to "seamlessly" continue, when you start vim anew. See also the help page for viminfo (start vim and type the command `:help viminfo`)

Comment: @SebastianStigler , thank you! very much, I actually love you now,
it was so simple... lol

Answer (score 7):

You can create a file named .exrc in your home directory and write all the commands (without the preceding : ) there.

> When you start the vi editor, the editor searches for the environment variable $EXINIT and uses the contents of the file it points to as configuration commands, if it exists.  If EXINIT is not defined, vi looks for the .exrc file in your HOME directory, and uses its configuration commands.  Finally, vi looks in your current directory for a file named .exrc and executes the commands in that file, if it exists.  In this manner, you can have a different vi configuration for each directory or project that you're working on.
>   (http://alvinalexander.com/unix/edu/un010003/)

The corresponding file for vim is called .vimrc.